# How to find json format of kubernetes command

Tags: kubernetes

I know that every command that I enter in Kubernetes communicate with API.

Now I want to **speak** to API **directly**. 
How can I find **json** format for every command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a client library if you talk from a programming language:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/#api-client-libraries

Or use `kubectl` if you talk from CLI. Hardcoding API schemas will add you a maintenance burden. You're basically reimplementing the client in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Following is the kubernetes API reference docs, you can find equivalent API for each resources here:

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks but it is complicatd. do you know simpler document?

Comment: Directly calling the API is a complicated affair. I also use Python client library. You should also use client library rather than calling the apis directly.

Comment: how can i use python library?